# Need help on understanding Razor syntax in a .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have got an already developed MVC 4 application and I have to fix some bugs in this project. I am facing a trouble regarding a syntax which are written like this in a .cshtml page . I am not getting any clue for what purpose this syntax is written and I am getting confused with the MVC Viewmodel concept.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RemoveImage) @PartnerNet.Resource.Client.ViewModel.RemoveLogo
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + "no-logo.png")" alt="@PartnerNet.Resource.Client.ViewModel.NoLogo" />
```

if I refer the dll defination it is showing like this when I am exploring the dll.Please give some ideas.

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace PartnerNet.Resource.Client
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [GeneratedCode("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public static string Address { get; }
        public static string AdminNotes { get; }
        public static string AlarmsActive { get; }
        public static string AlarmsHistory { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus_1 { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus_2 { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus0 { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus1 { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus2 { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus3 { get; }
        public static string AlarmStatus6 { get; }
        public static string AutoTreatment { get; }
        public static string AutoTreatmentCompletionStatus { get; }
        public static string AutoTreatmentLatest { get; }
```

Comment: Could you post the full `ViewModel`class definition?

Answer (score 0):

> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RemoveImage)@PartnerNet.Resource.Client.ViewModel.RemoveLogo

It says it is creating a checkbox for your current viewmodel with the name called RemoveImage in your view model.

It then adds text from the PartnerNet resource file and then loads the actual image and adds the alt tag again from the resource file.

A resource file is an mvc settings type file where text based values can be stored - example their will be a value store for the removelogo entry.

Hope that helps.